# Mac: determine model via teminal

Tags: macos, terminal

How can I determine the model of a Mac via command line (e.g., Mac Mini or Mac Pro)?

Comment: See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/can-a-macs-model-year-be-determined-via-terminal-command

Comment: Thank you. But isn't there a defaults command?

Comment: @Gabriel No. `defaults` is for reading and modifying preferences. The hardware model isn't a preference.

Comment: `defaults` reads settings and preferences. It cannot access HW infos

Comment: I see. I was trying to create a puppet module that would do an if statement based on the type. "if blah equals macpro do THIS, elseif blah equals min do THIS".

Comment: I believe there is a puppet facter way to do this. Time to googlefu this,

Answer (score 2):

Try `sysctl -n hw.model`. That should give the model as a string